# Ajax livesearch box

Tags: php, mysql, json, livesearch

Here's the html and javascript code :

```js
    $('document').ready(function(){
    $('input.typeahead').typeahead({
        name: 'typeahead',
        remote:'livesearch.php?key=%QUERY',
        limit : 10
    });
});
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Ajax Search Box using PHP and MySQL</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">        </script>
     <script src="typeahead.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
     <input type="text" name="typeahead">
</body>
</html>
```

The php file contains :

```
$key=$_GET['key'];
$array = array();
$query = $db->query(" SELECT * from product WHERE ProductName LIKE '%{$key}%' ") or die (mysql_error());
while($row = $query->fetch())
{
$array[] = $row['ProductName']; 
}
echo json_encode($array);
```

The php works absolutely fine. But I'm unable to get text in the input box

Comment: How can you tell it works fine? Can you see the php script being invoked when you type (Check Developer tools, network tab). Any script errors in the console? What/where is typeahead.js? If there is an error, it may be in there.

Comment: You are not selecting the input element. Use `$('input[name=typeahead]')`. Your selector is looking for input with **class** typeahead.

Comment: Note that your query is very unsafe. People can enter pieces of SQL code in the box and break your script or possibly damage your database.

Comment: @Golez Trol I used GET method just to check result from php file. Typehead.js contains that jquery code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
$('input[name=typeahead]')
```

to apply the typeahead function to the input element.